# TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method, when using CountVectorizer in a GridSearch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I'm practicing with some text using scikit-learn.

Towards getting more familiar with GridSearch, I am starting with some example code found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html):

```
###############################################################################
# define a pipeline combining a text feature extractor with a simple
# classifier
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer())
])

parameters = {
    'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0)
}
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Best score: %0.3f" % grid_search.best_score_)
```

Notice I am being very careful here, and I've only got one estimator and one parameter!

I'm finding that when I run this, I get the error:

```
TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator Pipeline(steps=[('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, decode_error=u'strict',
        dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None))]) does not.
```

Hummmm...why am I missing some sort of 'score' attribute?

When I check the possible parameters,

```
print CountVectorizer().get_params().keys()
```

I don't see anything where I can score, as was implied by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863944/scikit-learn-typeerror-if-no-scoring-is-specified-the-estimator-passed-should).

The documentation says `By default, parameter search uses the score function of the estimator to evaluate a parameter setting.` So why do I need to specify a score method?

Regardless, I thought I might need to explicity pass a `scoring` argument, but this didn't help and gave me an error:  `grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train, scoring=None)`

I don't understand this error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridSearch maximizes a score over the grid of parameters. You have to specify what kind of score to use because there are many different types of scores possible. For example, for classification problems, you could use accuracy, f1-score, etc. Usually, score type is specified by passing a string in the `scoring` argument (see [scoring parameter](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values)). Alternatively, model classes, like SVC or RandomForestRegressor, will have a `.score()` method. GridSearch will call that if no `scoring` argument is provided. However, that may or may not be the type of score that you want to optimize. There is also an option of passing in a function as the `scoring` argument if you have an unusual metric that you want GridSearch to use.

Transformers, like CountVectorizer, do not implement a score method, because they are just deterministic feature transformations. For the same reason, there aren't any scoring methods that make sense to apply to that type of object. You need a model class (or possibly a clustering algorithm) at the end of your pipeline for scoring to make sense.

Comment: Yes! Exactly. Thanks! This error message sure could be a little more descriptive. It's not that a CV is missing a score argument -- rather the pipeline is missing something that actually *does* scoring!

Comment: One question though if I may: say I have `pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDRegressor())
])`. Am I assured that it tries both `vect` --> `clf`, AND `tfidf` --> `clf`?

Comment: It will just score the output of the last step, the SGDRegressor. Before that, the pipeline runs your data through the transformer, and then uses the output of the transformer as input to the model. The predictions out of the model are what can be better or worse, so that's what gets scored.

Comment: Would it make sense to go `vect` --> `tfidf` --> `regressor` --> `classifier` or should I do a separate pipeline for each specific estimator? and THANK YOU for your help!

Comment: A pipeline will only call a `predict` method on the last estimator in the pipeline. If there is a regressor before a classifier, the pipeline will treat it like a transformer, not a model, and it will call its `transform` method, instead of its `predict` method. That usually doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck. I'm not sure I read your earlier question (second comment) correctly. In that pipeline, the data goes into the `CountVectorizer` and the output of that goes into the `TfidfTransformer`. Those aren't alternatives, both are applied to the data sequentially for every combination of parameters in the GridSearch.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I figured it out.

I wasn't understanding how the pipeline works. Sure, I could create a `CountVectorizer`, but why? There is no way you can get a score out of it, or basically do anything with it other than have a sparse matrix just sitting there.

I need to create a classifier (SGDRegressor) or a regressor (SGDClassifier).

I didn't realize that the pipeline will go

CV --> Regressor
or
CV --> Classifier

The pipeline does what it's name implies...pipes the objects together in series.

In other words, this works:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('clf', SGDRegressor())
])
```