# Scikit learn KerasClassifer evaluation error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I have created a Keras Classifier for k fold validation. Below is the function for building the classifer.

```
def build_classifier():

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu", input_dim=11, units=6, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu", units=6, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
classifier.add(Dense(activation="sigmoid", units=1, kernel_initializer="uniform"))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

return classifier
```

I have initialized the classifier as below.

```
    classfier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

I am trying to get the accuracy score from this 10 fold validation.

```
    accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
```

However it show me a TypeError:

> TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should
>   have a 'score' method. The estimator
>    does
>   not.

Comment: Show the imports. Which version of keras and scikit-learn are you using?

Comment: keras v2.2.2 and scikit-learn v0.19.1

Answer (score 0):

In cross_val_score pass scoring="accuracy" and it should work.
Similar solved question here: [Scikit-learn TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863944/scikit-learn-typeerror-if-no-scoring-is-specified-the-estimator-passed-should)

Comment: i did try adding scoring = "accuracy" but this is the error that i get. Cannot clone object '<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x00000219251B4A90>' (type <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.