# Implemening K-Fold Cross Validation, im getting this error TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, cross-validation, k-fold

**I have this code that builds the model and trains it aswell.**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'same' ,input_shape= input_shape))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same' ))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same' ))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Convolution2D(128, kernel_size = (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, kernel_size = (3,3), padding = 'same' ))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Dense(numclasses))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=["accuracy"])
hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=30, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks = callbacks_list)
```

**So i have 9000 images that i have trained as shown below, but as you can see there's a few signs of generalising taking place, i think if not please correct me**

[image]

**But anyway im trying to implement K-Fold Cross Validation.. there are soo many different ways to do it i guess but ive taken this approach as i thought it would be the easiest..**

```
#Applying K-Fold Cross Validation

accuracy = cross_val_score(estimator=model, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv=10)
accuracy.mean()
accuracy.std()
#Predicting the test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

**I have implemented other ways of doing K-Fold but i keep getting this error**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-181-765b62be4342> in <module>
      1 #Applying K-Fold Cross Validation
      2 
----> 3 accuracy = cross_val_score(estimator=model, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv=10)
      4 accuracy.mean()
      5 accuracy.std()

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflowenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    382     """
    383     # To ensure multimetric format is not supported
--> 384     scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
    385 
    386     cv_results = cross_validate(estimator=estimator, X=X, y=y, groups=groups,

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflowenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py in check_scoring(estimator, scoring, allow_none)
    293                 "If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should "
    294                 "have a 'score' method. The estimator %r does not."
--> 295                 % estimator)
    296     elif isinstance(scoring, Iterable):
    297         raise ValueError("For evaluating multiple scores, use "

TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f0ec5431860> does not.
```

> If anyone knows how to resolve this then please do help.. thank you!

Comment: Have you tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863944/scikit-learn-typeerror-if-no-scoring-is-specified-the-estimator-passed-should)?

Comment: Yes. i have tried to implement it, but i may be struggling on how to adapt it towards my code ... is it because im not using a method ? @DanielBlei

Comment: I don't have the right tools to check at the moment. I don't know if this can help you but there is [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38020/using-k-fold-cross-validation-in-keras-on-the-data-of-my-model) a person mentioning a problem with Keras and Sklearn. Maybe try to do the Kfold before:

`kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)`
`  `

`accuracy = cross_val_score(estimator=model, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv=kfold)`

Comment: @DanielBlei Okayy Thank you! because the question posted there is the two errors i get when i implement Kfold Cross-Validation in different ways.. i try what you gave me first.. ill keep you informed thanks!